# Split ReportLab table between multiple pages using Canvas

Tags: pdf, reportlab

My table is too long and goes beyond one page.

I know it's easy to fix this with doc.build, however I am using canvas.save and am wondering if its possible to split the table across multiple pages without switching all my code over to doc.build.

Here is some example code:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.colors import pink, green, brown, white, black, gray
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

canvas = canvas.Canvas("CoverSheet.pdf", pagesize=letter)

data = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
table = Table(data)

table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black),
                       ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black),
                       ]))
w, h = table.wrapOn(canvas, inch * 1, inch * 4)
table.drawOn(canvas, inch * 1, inch * 1 - h)
canvas.save()
```

What do I need to do to get the table to continue on the next page?